# Show that $\forall x, x' \in X$ there are open sets $U, U' \subseteq X$ s.t. $x \in U, x' \in U'$, & $U \cap U' = \emptyset$

Tags: general-topology

> Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space. Show that for every $x, x' \in X$ there are open sets $U, U' \subseteq X$ such that $x \in U, x' \in U'$, and $U \cap U' = \emptyset$.

So if $d(x,x')=n$, we can choose the diameter of the ball to be $n/2$ so that $U \cap U' = \emptyset$. But how do we know that $U, U' \subseteq X$? For example, let's say that $X=[0,1]$ and $x=1$, then $x$ is on the edge and we cannot draw an open ball around it, right? So I'm not really sure how I can prove that $U,U' \subseteq X$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The space $X$ is the universe, there is nothing outside it. The balls are by definition contained in $X$.

Comment: If you want to talk about balls, then $B(1,\epsilon) = ]1-\epsilon, 1]$ (in the metric space $[0,1]$) and is an open set. Consider that there is nothing living outside $X$, as Daniel said.

Comment: @Did: Oh indeed, sorry about this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In every metric space $X$, for every $r\gt0$, the set $B(x,r)=\{y\in X\mid d(x,y)\lt r\}$ is an open set of $X$, called the open ball centered at $x$ with radius $r$. Hence, for every $x\ne x'$ in $X$, your question is solved by $U=B(x,r)$ and $U'=B(x',r)$ for $r$ positive and small enough, say $r=\frac12d(x,x')$.

Note that if $X=[0,1]$ and $d$ is the usual distance then $B(1,r)=(1-r,1]$ for every $r\leqslant1$. For example, the set $(\frac23,1]$ is an open ball.

Comment: Thanks, but if $B(x,r)$ is open for any $x$ and $r$ in an arbitrary set $X$, isn't that like saying that all sets are open? I thought the set was $[a,b]$ was closed for any $a,b$.

Comment: Yes every B(x,r) (with r positive) is open. No, all sets are not open, for exemple A=[2/3,1] is not open in X=[0,1] with the usual metric since A contains no open ball B(2/3,r) (with r positive) although A contains 2/3, and yes, this A is closed since its complement is C=[0,2/3) which is open since C=B(0,2/3). Note that C is also C=B(1/6,1/2).

Answer (score 2):

In a metric space, an open ball with centre $p$ of radius $r$ is **by definition** the set of all $y$ **in the space** such that $d(p,y)\lt r$. It need not coincide with our intuitive notion of open ball.

Note that to be picky, we should specify that $x\ne x'$. Then your argument is fine. It is, however, somewhat incomplete. To show that the two balls have empty intersection, you should make explicit use of the Triangle Inequality.

Comment: But this question doesn't even make sense when $x = x'$, right? Because then it would be impossible for the intersection of $U$ and $U'$ to be the empty set, since both $x$ and $x'$ are in both open sets.

Comment: The question would formally make sense, it's just that the result would be trivially false, as you point out. Of course it is *intended* that we assume that $x\ne x'$. But the question doesn't specify. In a lecture, that's fine, but in written material one should be exact.